# Angular2: Injecting Router in myExceptionHAndler

Tags: angular, typescript

In my `app.module.ts` I have :

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpModule
    ],
    providers: [
        {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyExceptionHandler}
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then in my `MyExceptionHandler`:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core"
import { Router } from "@angular/router"

@Injectable()
export class MyExceptionHandler {
    constructor (private _router: Router) {}

    handleError(error:any):void {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, I am having an error saying : `Error: Error: Provider parse errors`

If I use MyExceptionHandler as an usual provider, it works fine. So my guess would be that the ErrorHandler gets handled before the Router exactly exists. Anyway to fix this ?

Comment: Can you please try to inject `Injector` instead of `Router` and use `this._router = injector.get(Rotuer);`. Injecting into `ErrorHandler` often causes circular dependencies which can be worked around this way. I also think your `MyExceptionHandler` should implement `ErrorHandler`.

Comment: Well, would you be able to provide an example of how to inject Injector ?

Comment: `constructor(injector:Injector) { this._router = injector.get(Rotuer); }` ;-)

Comment: Yeah ok, but do I need to declare : 
const injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([]);
expect(injector.get(Injector)).toBe(injector);

Somewhere ?

Comment: What has that code to do with the question? Is this about testing? Have you actually tried my suggestion?

Comment: Hi, I did try it indeed, unfortunately I got : 
Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'componentTypes' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'componentTypes' of undefined(…) TypeError: Cannot read property 'componentTypes' of undefined

That's why I thought something was missing

Comment: Sounds like https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10671 Seems there is something wrong with your project outside the code you posted.

Comment: The two issues mentionned over there were 1) importing Http instead of HttpModule 2) Using services in declarations instead of providers. And both are correct in my case, I will keep looking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9843 working code will look like:

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {
    private _router: Router;
    constructor(private _injector: Injector) {
        // The true parameter tells Angular to rethrow exceptions, 
        // so operations like 'bootstrap' will result in an error
        // when an error happens. If we do not rethrow, 
        // bootstrap will always succeed.
        super(true);
    }

    handleError(error: any): void {
        // Delegate to the default handler.
        super.handleError(error);

        if (!this._router) {
            this._router = this._injector.get(Router);
        }

        // TODO: log error and then redirect to 500 page.
        this._router.navigate(['/errors/500']);
    }
}
```